# How do I highlight books with added metadata in Calibre Reader

Tags: metadata, ebook, calibre

I'm busy importing a large number of books from diverse folders on my machine. Often, at first Calibre knows nothing about the book, and I tag it and download metadata from Amazon. Then I'm back looking at a grid where all books look the same. Is there a way I can let Calibre flag books I have 'processed' vs. those unknowns just imported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In cover view, it is possible to use rules to show an icon next to a book cover. To do this, you go to `Preferences > Look and Feel > Cover Grid > Emblems`, and click `Add Rule`. In my example, I told it to show the tick icon if the Author wasn't `Unknown`, and there was a title value. You would just need to go through and set the rule to what you should have filled in for the book.

If you view your books in list view, you can do `Column coloring` in a similar way to highlight rows/columns in your specified color when rules are met.

[image]